# Selecting some dates in Calendar while initializing it

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-datepicker, android-date

I am using `CalenderView` in android. I have a list of predefined dates as `["2019-02-15","2019-02-16","2019-02-17"]`. When Calender is initialized and shown on `Activity/fragment` i want this dates to be selected.How to achieve this.
I am initializing calender this way

```
calender=v.findViewById(R.id.cal);
   calender.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000);
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Which calendar are you using?

Comment: default CalenderView of android

Comment: Do you mean that you need to disable all other dates other than the array of dates?

Comment: No. Only the dates in List should be highlighted or selected

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the Android API Reference you find this function:

```
CalendarView.setDate(long date)
```

*Sets the selected date in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 in TimeZone.getDefault() time zone.* https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html#setDate(long)

So in your case you should call:

```
calender.setDate(long date);
```

In order to get the milliseconds, you should first parse your date string and then convert them to milliseconds.

Additionally I am not sure and I dont't think that it is possible to select more than one date at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable specific dates in the default CalendarView of android, for that you've to fork that widget and do your customisation. Then the other option is to use third party libraries like

[material-calendarview](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)

Using this library you can easily disable custom dates and apply custom background color and so on.

[Material-Calendar-View](https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View)

This is also other third party option which provides multiple date selection and so on.